# Compiling multithread code with g++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, g++

I have the easiest code ever:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void worker()
{
    std::cout << "another thread";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(worker);
    std::cout << "main thread" << std::endl;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

though I still cannot compile it with `g++` to run.

More details:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Command to compile:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main.out -pthread -std=c++11
```

Running:

```
$ ./main.out 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And now I'm in stuck. In every related thread over the internet it's recommended to add `-pthread` while I have it already.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: It's a brand new ubuntu 13.10 installation. Only `g++` package was installed and minor things like `chromium` etc

PPS:

```
$ ldd ./a.out 
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff29fc1000) 
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb85397d000) 
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb853767000) 
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb85339e000) 
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb85309a000) 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb853c96000)
```

PPPS: with `clang++` (v3.2) it compiles and runs fine

PPPPS: guys, it's not a duplicate of [What is the correct link options to use std::thread in GCC under linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649828/what-is-wrong-with-this-use-of-stdthread)

PPPPPS:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep 'libc.*dev'
libc-dev-bin                    install
libc6-dev:amd64                 install
libclang-common-dev             install
linux-libc-dev:amd64                install
```

Comment: It's a symlink to `libpthread-2.17.so` in the same directory.

Comment: Yes, that is a correct link.  Here is my dir




lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       18 Sep 12 20:52 libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.16.so

Comment: @Jason Enochs: it would work for me - I agree, if I didn't use buggy gcc version

Comment: Yea, all of your libraries are a bit newer than mine:
gcc version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8) (GCC)

Comment: @Jason Enochs: hehe. For myself I'm already satisfied with "it's a bug" answer, and probably will try to run it on an older ubuntu tomorrow, just to be completely sure

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The answer was provided by a kind member of [SO C++ chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12447014#12447014).

It looks like this behaviour is caused by a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201) in gcc.

The workaround provided in the last comment of that bug discussion **does** work and solves the issue:

```
-Wl,--no-as-needed
```

Comment: What would I do without SO and guys like you? You saved me a headful of hair pulling. Thanks :) This is as obscure as it gets (for me at least)

Comment: @scorpiodawg: your comment made my evening, thanks :-)

Comment: I had to add all of the `-pthread -lpthread -Wl,--no-as-needed` flags in order to get this work.

Answer (score 38):

Adding `-lpthread` fixed the identical problem for me:

```
 g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp -lpthread -o foo
```

Comment: Jep, this is the anwser and also completely reasonable. "-Wl,--no-as-needed" sounded weird and also doesn't work for me.

Comment: You definitely need `-lpthread`. You *might* need `-pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed`, depending on compiler version. **gcc-4.8.2** needs it.

Answer (score 15):

I have slightly more advanced version (4.8.4 instead of 4.8.1), and I tested all three answers above.  In fact:

`-pthread` alone works:

> g++ -std=c++11 -o main -pthread main.cpp

`-Wl,--no-as-needed` alone **does not work**.

`-lpthread` alone **does not work**.

`-Wl,--no-as-needed` and `-lpthread` ***together*** work:

> g++ -std=c++11 -o main -Wl,--no-as-needed main.cpp -lpthread

My version is "g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4".

Comment: Well, the solutions were provided for the different version and I can assure the checked answer did work at the moment I checked it. Anyway, thanks for the actual info.

Answer (score 10):

answer already was made
for qtcreator:

```
LIBS += -pthread
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -pthread
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

for console g++: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274032/c-threads-stdsystem-error-operation-not-permitted?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
g++ -c main.cpp -pthread -std=c++11         // generate target object file
g++ main.o -o main.out -pthread -std=c++11  // link to target binary
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is the only one that makes it clear that the -pthread has to be passed to the compiler and the linker.