# Thread doesn't work with an error: Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, multithreading

I created and executed a simple thread on my system. when I execute this program, I have the error message : **Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted**

some details about my system :

- linux ubuntu 13.10
- g++ 4.8.1

I compile the source code including the library `pthread`

The source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


using namespace std;

void func(void) {
  cout << "test thread" << endl;
}


int main() {
  cout << "start" << endl;
  thread t1 (func);

  t1.join();

  cout << "end" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I removed the `java` tag and added `C/Cpp`...

Comment: @home Why did you add C? This is C++, not C...

Comment: Oh and BTW this doesn't even compile. Missing hash signs before the preprocessor directives... And there's no indentation. Fix your code.

Comment: I have feeling that you want to use new C++11 threads. In order to compile this you need to compile with `-std=c++11` switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling multithread code with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g).

Comment: You need to compile with the `-pthread` and `-std=c++11` compiler flags.

Comment: In g++ 4.8.1, characters of c11 is implicit, try to add `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread` explicitly.

Comment: according to the accepted answer in the duplicate, you need these options with gcc 4.8: `-pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed`

Comment: @home I didn't ask why you removed the Java tag. I asked why you added the C tag, when this code is clearly not C.

Comment: @H2CO3: got it, I just was not sure whether it's about C or Cpp (not my 'core' business)...

Comment: In addition to answer 1, check the following link too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g

Answer (score 36):

It seems that you are trying to use C++11 threads. If it is true, then

1. correct `#include <thread>` and `#include <iostream>`, i.e. do not use `"` in these lines and add `#` in front of them.
2. compile with `g++ -std=c++11 q.cpp -lpthread` (dependency order matters for newer g++)

Hint: when you are using threads in a static linked library and use this library in an executable, then you have to add the flag `-pthread` to the link command for the executable. Example:

```
g++ Obj1.o Obj2.o MyStaticLib.a -o MyExecutable -pthread
```

Comment: To be clearer: the problem was in missing of __-pthread__ flag of gcc for a moment of compilaion. If it was `#include`s, the code just wouldn't compiled.

Comment: Why is -pthreads necessary? Is this also needed in non C++11 code?

Comment: Not required by the standard but implementation specific @MrMowgli