# Error creating std::threads in Ubuntu 13.10 x64 C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, ubuntu-13.10

I don't know what is happening in my Ubuntu 13.10. All my functions using std::threads are throwing the error message :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>   what():  Operation not permitted Aborted (core dumped)

This same program works perfectly in Ubuntu 13.04 64 and 32 bits... I didn't change the g++ parameters in the Makefile.. It seems to be a bug of Ubuntu 13.10 x64..

Can anyone help me?

( Sorry for my bad English )

Comment: show some code... it's gonna be easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling multithread code with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g)

Comment: @LucasLellis It's not your fault, see the linked question for the solution.

Comment: Thank's for the help.. I think they solved this issue in recent updates ^^

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing the -phtread switch when compiling. If you link in a seperate step you need to add the switch -lpthread to you commandline.