# std::promise<T>::set_value() on Ubuntu 13.10 ends with "unknown error -1" (std::system_error)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, promise, future

The following cpp code doesn't run on Ubuntu 13.10 using g++-4.8 or g++-4.7. I have no idea how to solve that issue. It seems that on older Ubuntu versions (e.g. 13.04) the code below works fine.

### Code

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int step = 0;
    std::cout << "step " << ++step << std::endl;

    std::promise<int> promise;
    std::cout << "step " << ++step << std::endl;

    try
    {
        promise.set_value(42);
        std::cout << "step " << ++step << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::system_error& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

### Build And Run

```
g++ promise_test.cpp -o promise_test -pthread -std=c++11 && ./promise_test
```

### Output

```
step 1
step 2
Exception: Unknown error -1
```

Comment: Try catching std::system_error and seeing what `ex.what()` tells you. Although I doubt it'll give more information.

Comment: `ex.what()` returns just `Unknown error -1`

Comment: Try `-Wl,--no-as-needed`

Comment: Seems to work! Thanks! (now I have to make sure that I understand the parameters as well :) )

Comment: It's a Ubuntu 13.10 bug, but the error is usually 'operation not permitted'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201). The work around provided is `-Wl,--no-as-needed`. See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative we fixed it with `-static-libstdc++` flag.