# Compiling multithread code with g++ (-Wl,--no-as-needed NOT working)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, g++

My problem is actually described here: [Compiling multithread code with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g). 
But the answer regarding the work around by using "-Wl,--no-as-needed" is not working for me.

I've added `-Wl,--no-as-needed -pthread -std=c++0x` in different orders also, but I still get the:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted"
```

What to do?

```
Info: 
Ubuntu 12.04LTS
Running Eclipse CDT
g++ v4.8.1
```

**Edit:** 
I tried building with `-Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread -std=c++0x` with no luck. 
The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Thread 1 created.." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(foo);

    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:
So unfortunately none of your suggestions worked. I decided to use Boost instead.**

Comment: That bug is corrected in GCC 4.8.2; try to upgrade to it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: How can I upgrade to GCC 4.8.2? 
`sudo apt-get upgrade gcc` wont do it..

Comment: You could install a [Debian/Sid gcc 4.8](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gcc-4.8) package, or compile [FSF GCC 4.8.2](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.2/) source code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I'm having difficulties install gcc v4.8.2 since a package is not officially created for Ubuntu 12.04.. I'm considering just trying Boost instead ..

Answer (score 4):

1. it's `-Wl,--no-as-needed` not `-Wl,--no_as_needed`, you use the hyphen
2. `-pthread` is a flag for the compiler, not the linker, the right one for the linker is `-lpthread`
3. Mingw doesn't always comes with the same threading library, there are more than 1 options for multithreading with MinGW, you should document yourself about this according to your MinGW build

Comment: Your (1) and (3) are correct, but the compiler (technically, the "driver" program that is installed as `/usr/bin/gcc`; `-v` will show you what it does) converts `-pthread` to `-lpthread` when it is asked to perform a link.

Comment: @Zack yes, in other words the `-pthread` flag alone should be enough, but in my experience it's not, I have encountered situations where `pthread` doesn't activate `lthread`, It was probably due to some customization for the given `gcc` build that I was using, but sometimes I have found the `-lpthread` flag necessary even with `pthread`.

Comment: 1. Typo mistake.
2. I tried with `-Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread -std=c++0x` and had no luck. Still same error message.
3. My toolchain is set to "Linux GCC", so I don't think I'm using MinGW?

Comment: @user2485710 Still same error with `-std=c++0x -pthread`. Or `-std=c++0x -lpthread` (tried both).. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

```
g++  filename.c -std=c++11 -lpthread
```

i am compiling your code with above command its working perfect.

Comment: See the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201