# Link Time Optimization conflicting with multithreading support

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, g++, lto

As I've read about improved link time optimization support in `g++-4.9`, I want to give it a try. Sadly, I get exceptions at run time, specifically `std::system_error`with `e.what() == Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted`.

Now I normally know how to fix that error: add `-pthread` to my compiler invokation, but in fact, I already have this parameter!

My sample code is:

```
#include <thread>

int main()
{
   std::thread t([](){}); // do nothing in a thread!
   t.join();              // wait for nothing to be done
}
```

Compiled with (X being 7, 8 or 9)

```
g++-4.X -std=c++11 -pthread test.cpp -o thread_test_fine
```

works flawlessly as expected, no runtime error.

However,

```
g++-4.X -std=c++11 -pthread -flto test.cpp -o thread_test_runtime_error
```

fails with the `system_error` exception.

Question:

Is this behavior intended (what's the fix?) or is it a bug?

(Before this question may come up: my compilers are all build with `--enable-threads=posix`)

Comment: What is your linker ?

Comment: @quantdev I suppose that's GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24.51.20140612 (I actually never cared for the linker yet, so I'm kind of a noob with that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this parameters:

```
-Wl,--no-as-needed
```

If it helps then it's a `gcc` bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19463892/280758