# thread with code::blocks error at runtime

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, codeblocks

Compile this file:

```
//Create a C++11 thread from the main program

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

//This function will be called from a thread
void call_from_thread()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, from thread! " << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, from main! " << std::endl;

    //Launch a thread
    std::thread t1(call_from_thread);

    //Join the thread with the main thread
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

using code::blocks with the copmpiler option "use C++11" checked.

code::blocks compiler says: g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -pthread  -c /home/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o

note that the -std=c++11 -pthread was passed to the compiler.

When running the programm,got this message:

```
Hello, from main! 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)

Process returned 134 (0x86)   execution time : 0.110 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

how to get this work?
thanks for helping.

====================

PS. I have seen this post [Compiling multithread code with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g). Then tried to use the trick

I tried this:

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -pthread -Wl --no-as-needed  -c /home/olivier/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o

but got the following.

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--no-as-needed’
```

Comment: And the code causing this is ... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling multithread code with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g)

Comment: did you even search?

Comment: code added.  I have seen the "compiling multithread code wwith g++" but I could not use this workaround with code::blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with -pthread you should link with -lpthread.

The second is easy, it must be:`-Wl,--no-as-needed` (',' is missing), but it is used for the linker. Your call only compiles into an object file, so you can erase that.

Another note on the second one, it might be that you actually have to link with `-Wl,--no-as-needed` due to [a bug in some gcc version](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201)

As for Code::Blocks, you can add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` and -lpthread in the linker tab of the build options.

Comment: Thank-you very much, Yamakuzure