# How to get the multithreaded working in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, codeblocks

[image: The Build log][image][image]I have code which uses multithread ability of C++11. I am able to execute the code in the terminal using the comm[image]and:

g++ main.cpp -o main -pthread -std=c++11

But I am unable to execute the same code from the CodeBlocks. Whenever I attempt to do it, it throws the error : terminate called after throwing an instance of std::system_error what(): Enable multithreading....

I know that Codeblocks, is building the code without '-pthread' in it, but I don't know to add that in CodeBlocks.

[image]

Comment: did you join your thread? I'm not able to see that in your code...

Comment: @codekiddy: I did join and on terminal the correct is generated.....

Comment: See if this helps; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g

Comment: @skn Please post the build log of your build (from clean). You'll find it under the **Build log** (not **Build messages**) tab.

Comment: @MikeKinghan : I have uploaded a screenshot for the build log, please do have a look

Comment: Please replace the screenshot by text. There's roughly 95% useless information in the pictures and they are fairly small and hard to read.

Comment: The build Log::::                                                                                   g++ -Wall -fexceptions -pthread -std=c++11  -c /home/subhadeep/Desktop/TestStack/StackOverflow/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/StackOverflow obj/Debug/main.o   
Output file is bin/Debug/StackOverflow with size 49.78 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `-pthread` from **Build options** -> **Compiler settings** -> **Other options** and add it to
**Build options** -> **Linker settings** -> **Other options**, then rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

To add the compiler flag -pthread: Go to Project -> Build Options -> Compiler Settings tab -> Other Options and enter `-pthread`

Comment: The error still persists I posted the screenshot, please have a look and let me know if there is anything that you can help me with