# C++11 thread boost container

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost

A simple code with C++11 thread:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void thread_task(){
    std::cout<<"hello, here is thread task with state:"<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread t(thread_task);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

compile:

```
g++ -pthread -std=c++11 -O0 -Wall -g -ggdb  main.cpp  -o main  -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_serialization

./main can execute right!
```

--

```
g++ -pthread -std=c++11 -O0 -Wall -g -ggdb  main.cpp  -o main  -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_serialization -lboost_container-mt

g++ -pthread -std=c++11 -O0 -Wall -g -ggdb  main.cpp  -o main  -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_serialization -lboost_container 

./main all will have an error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
[1]    29643 abort (core dumped)  ./main
```

why -lboost_container lead to this error? Certainly, boost_container is no need in my code example. It is noly a example.

Comment: Probably related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g

Comment: try to link with pthread library. `g++ ... -lpthread`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux -pthread is the portabler way to achieve the required linker inputs/flags for POSIX threads support.

Comment: g++ -o threads thread.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
./threads
hello, here is thread task with state:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was answered[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g)

```
g++ -Wl,--no-as-needed -pthread -std=c++11 -O0 -Wall -g -ggdb  main.cpp  -o main  -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_serialization -lboost_container
```