# Thread header not found with g++ compiler

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-errors

I am trying to make a basic multithreaded application in c++ using the g++ compiler (mingw32 9.2.0). The code I am using:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int N = 0;
void dostuff() {
    N++;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(dostuff);
    std::cout << N;

}
```

However, this simple code fails to compile, with g++ saying `'thread' is not a member of 'std'` (compiling with `g++ -pthread -std=c++0x test.cpp -o test`, and also hilariously saying `did you forget to '#include <thread>'`, and showing *corrected* code with `#include <thread>` right below where I put it! You can see that [here](https://snipboard.io/jXxoh6.jpg).

I am at a complete loss as to why this doesn't work - I have searched around, using [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g) and also [this one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=97748), to no avail.

Comment: The plain MinGW doesn't support threads, you want MinGW-w64. There are several distributions, the good ones are https://www.msys2.org/ and https://winlibs.com/