# g++ 4.8.1 C++ Threads, std::system_error - operation not permitted?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, g++

This is not a duplicate question, because the solutions presented are not working on my compiler. I am trying to compile and run the following example [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649828/what-is-the-correct-link-options-to-use-stdthread-in-gcc-under-linux).

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **){
    std::thread tt([](){ std::cout<<"Thread!"<<std::endl; });
    tt.join();
}
```

I have attempted to use the solutions presented in both that original question as well as the accepted answer to [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274032/c-threads-stdsystem-error-operation-not-permitted). However, although I tried all the combinations listed, and in particular tried

```
g++  main.cpp -o main.out -pthread -std=c++11
```

When I run the resulting executable, I still get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is the output of `g++ --version`.

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Is there a different ordering or set of commands I need to use for `g++ 4.8.1`?

Comment: 4.8.1 has a bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201

Comment: I see. Unfortunately the proposed workaround also doesn't work. 
I hope someone on SO knows a better workaround.

Comment: Double check that you aren't running a previously built version of your application.

Comment: I manually remove the executable before I rebuild just to be sure.

Comment: Use Clang. I don't use Gcc for c++11 & 14 related stuff. Because clang is just simply faster than Gcc to implement these new features. And compiling Clang now is just like a piece of case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g)

```
g++ -Wl,--no-as-needed -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp -o main.out
```