# Linux gnu++11, getting "Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted" on runtime

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am using C++11 thread with my project, on runtime I am getting the followiung:

```
"Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted"
```

Reading [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274032/c-threads-stdsystem-error-operation-not-permitted) I have added -lpthread to link against the pthreads library, still I get the same error...

Compilation Snap

```
g++ -ggdb -ffunction-sections -O0 -lpthread -std=gnu++11   -DDEBUG  -c HID.cpp -o Debug/HID.o -MD -MF Debug/HID.dep
```

How can I avoid the runtime exception? any caviats for using "-std=gnu++11" rather than "-std=c++11" ?

Comment: Use -pthread rather than -lpthread, for both compiling *and* linking.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem, I have added pthread as compilation switch while forgetting to add it as linker switch

Answer (score 0):

Trying using -pthread instead of -lpthread.

---

Answer (score 0):

Add : -lpthread
after the source file on the build command line.