# CMake Linking Error pthread: Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, multithreading, cmake, pthreads

I have a similar error like another had before
[C++ Threads, std::system_error - operation not permitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274032/c-threads-stdsystem-error-operation-not-permitted)

I am using exactly the same source code and compiling with

```
g++ ../src/main.cpp -pthread -std=c++11
```

works without any problem.

Since I want to use threads in a larger project I have to use threads with CMake. After searching for solutions I found several codes for example:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Test)
add_definitions("-std=c++11")

find_package (Threads)
add_executable (main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (main ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

But for me it's not working I get always:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is my mistake?

The CMake output looks promising:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct link options to use std::thread in GCC under linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649828/what-is-the-correct-link-options-to-use-stdthread-in-gcc-under-linux)

Comment: You need to add `pthread` to your linker settings in cmake

Comment: check what `find_package (Threads)` has done: what libs are found?

Comment: directly use `-pthread` options is okay.

Answer (score 22):

> **EDIT**: I am now using `gcc 5.4`, the CMake snippet in question just work fine.

I just faced the same problem.My final `CMakeLists.txt`, which works, is as follows (note - it will work for Windows as well, i.e.- using Visual Studio):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Test)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-std=c++11 -pthread")

find_package (Threads)
add_executable (main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (main ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

EDIT 2: As of CMake 3.2, there is an `IMPORTED` target you link to instead:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2)
project (Test)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package (Threads)
add_executable (main src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (main Threads::Threads)
```

(it might be 3.1.3, but I cannot find the change in the release notes)

Comment: +1 had the same issue, all the "standard" ways of enabling multithreading in gnu c++ did not work when cross-compiling for my raspberry pi. This snippet, however, solved the issues. Thanks

Comment: @BirgerSkogengPedersen Glad to hear that

Comment: Note that this snippet is linking the same lib in two different ways.  The ```-pthread``` works by itself, or the ```find_package``` + ```target_link_libraries``` calls.  Only one of those two methods is needed (I would say the latter is preferred).

Comment: @ChuckClaunch Maybe for lower gcc version(such like 4.8), we should use cmake in some way as my snippet showing. I tried on gcc 5.4 a few seconds ago, both `-pthread` or `find_package + target_link_libraries` runs smoothly.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Right, both work, however it's redundant to use both at the same time.  And you must be careful because ```-pthread``` could potentially link against a different library than ```find_package``` depending on your system and CMake environment.  For what it's worth, the cmake way of using ```find_package``` + ```target_link_libraries``` works perfectly in a cross-platform application I'm working on right now.  I've shown it to work in Ubuntu 15.04, CentOS 7, and Windows 10.  All without the ```-pthread``` flag set or any extra ```if```s related to Windows.

Comment: @ChuckClaunch Please read the question carefully, when working with `gcc 4.8.2`, there are problems without `pthread` flag.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I read the question just fine. Nowhere on this page (nor in the original question) is gcc mentioned except for you saying in a comment that "maybe" gcc 4.8 could operate differently.  What I'm telling you is the two methods of linking the library are redundant.  If you need to use the ```-pthread``` option for it to work, fine, then remove the CMake way of doing it.  You absolutely do not need both.

Comment: @ChuckClaunch We can see `The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2` in the question, so Julian was using GCC 4.8.2 at the time. He meet problem without the optinon `-pthread`. I am now using GCC 5.4 so I can not reproduce it.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin ok I see that in his output.  Either way it still found the threading library and successfully linked.  He had a runtime problem.  It's more important to someone troubleshooting to learn what happened w/the correct way (finding out what the ```find_package``` call did, rather than just assuming the system pthread was ok.  It's a band-aid to just link it with a gcc def.  Sounds like OP had a permission issue or might have had multiple threading libraries installed.

Comment: @ChuckClaunch I think there maybe bugs within gcc 4.8, for the deference with `-pthread` and `-lpthread`, please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling, there are indeed some difference.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin There may indeed be a bug (though I don't see where you conclude that based on the reference), I simply don't want someone looking at this answer as the correct way to use the threading library in a CMake project.  I will leave it at that.

Comment: @ChuckClaunch I will edit the answer to add some supplement， thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Linux desktop), setting the flag is enough:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT (threads_tests)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-std=c++11 -pthread")
ADD_EXECUTABLE(threads_1 threads_1.cpp)
```

but explicitly finding the library and linking with it also works and may be necessarily for some crosscompile situations with embedded platforms.